# Регулярное выражение: разный результат при одном и том же сравнении

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Простейшая регулярка и я не пойму в чем ошибка. Нужно проверять что бы в строке не было "@"

Моя регулярка

```
reg = /^[^@]{3,30}$/g;
```

но при использовании вижу следующее

```js
reg = /^[^@]{3,30}$/g;
console.log(reg.test('dddd')); //true
console.log(reg.test('ddddd')); //false
```

Как так?

Comment: для проверки `@` не нужна регулярка

Comment: задание через регулярку

Comment: делайте `'ddd'.search( /^[^@]{3,30}$/g )`

Comment: @Jean-Claude вопрос не в том, как сделать, а почему получается как получается. без флага `g` к примеру, работает и приведенный вариант.  и зачем `search` который более ресурсоемок использовать?

Comment: а у меня `true` выводит

Comment: @Grundy у меня  при вводе в консоль одного и того же несколько раз reg.test('dddd'); выводит то true, то false )) firefox

Comment: а через функцию почему то нормально https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Comment: @Jean-Claude, все правильно. особенность `test`

Comment: вот нашел ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-does-a-regexp-with-global-flag-give-wrong-results

Comment: _"метод test(), вызванный несколько раз на одном и том же экземпляре регулярного выражения, будет начинать проверку с конца предыдущего сопоставления."_ в этом дело, или нет?

Comment: @teran А можете объяснить почему так?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как указано в [справке](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

> Как и при вызове метода exec() (или при совместном с ним вызове), метод test(), вызванный несколько раз на одном и том же экземпляре регулярного выражения, будет начинать проверку с конца предыдущего сопоставления.

Поэтому при следующем вызове `reg.test` проверка идет не с начала строки, а, в данном случае, с 4 индекса.

Как указано в [английском ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1520853/2881286) это происходит из-за флага `g`.

В случае его отсутствия работать будет ожидаемо:

```js
reg = /^[^@]{3,30}$/;
console.log(reg.test('dddd')); //true
console.log(reg.test('ddddd')); //false
```

Comment: а после четвертого опять с нулевого?

Comment: @Jean-Claude, с нулевого начинается после достижения конца строки

Comment: в итоге то получается, что не работает второй вызов из-за того, что с 4го символа это не ^-начало строки, и оставшийся 1 символ не влезает в длину от 3х. Если убрать `^$` то получается нагляднее. строки после вызова `dddd` не пройдет вызова `ddddd` (остаток меньше 3х), пройдет `ddddddd` (остаток 3), и пройдет `d@ddddd` так как @ раньше 4го и не проверяется.

Comment: у вас же в примере выводится //true //true

Comment: @teran Вот это {ddddddd} не пройдет! после 4-ч символов начинается чередование, т.е если нечетное число то {false}, если четное то {true}

Comment: @Slava я вроде написал, что без `^$`

Comment: @teran прости, виноват! Но я не пойму почему в этом примере `reg = /^[^@]{3,30}$/g;` идет чередование `true` `false`