# Есть регулярное выражение, поиск русских слов

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Полная запись такая:

```
/\b(admin|bot)\b/gmi.test(elems.name.value)
```

Как модифицировать чтобы находила `[а-яА-ЯёЁ]` в совпадениях?

Задача: искать совпадения русских слов в строке, с использованием:

```
/\b(Админ|Бот)\b/gmi
```

Comment: Нужна ли поддержка любых (старых) браузеров? Или можно предположить, что используется современная версия JS с поддержкой ECMAScript 2018?

Comment: поддержка ie11, без babel

Comment: Если вам нужна общая поддержка всех букв, без `XRegExp` не обойтись. Если нужна поддержка только английских и русских, тут можно и символьными классами отделаться.

Comment: Можете привести пример с символьными классами как правильно написать?

Comment: [Не используйте в регулярках для `test()` модификатора `g`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/752701/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать выражение типа

```
/(?:^|[^a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ])(?:слово1|слово2|словоN)(?![a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ])/
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/ZUlGXM/1)

**Подробности**

- `(?:^|[^a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ])` - незахватывающая подмаска, либо начало строки, либо любой символ, отличный от русской и английской буквы
- `(?:слово1|слово2|словоN)` - одно из перечисленных слов...
- `(?![a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ])` - сразу после которого не должно быть русской или английской буквы.

```js
var keywords = ['admin', 'bot', 'админ', 'бот'];
var reg = new RegExp("(?:^|[^a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ])(?:" + keywords.join("|") + ")(?![a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ])");

var tests = ["admin,here", "administrator", "A bot!!!", "no bottle", "админ", "администратор", "работяга"];
for (var i=0; i<tests.length; i++) {
   console.log(tests[i], "=>", reg.test(tests[i]));
}
```